# Can I damage a docking station by plugging in a possibly-fried hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, docking-station

I may have fried a hard drive using a Molex-to-Sata adapter and I'd like to check if it's dead by connecting it to a new docking station.

Is this safe to do? Can I damage the docking station by connecting the hard drive if the drive turns out to be fried?

The drive is 3.5" and the docking station uses external power supply.

Comment: Probably not - and its a pretty standard way to test

Answer (score 0):

As Journeyman Geek said in his comment: It is unlikely you'll hurt the dock by connecting a failed drive to it. And yes, this is how professionals test drives too.

That said, there's always a chance. Nothing is 100% bullet-proof.

Ways to mitigate the already-small likelihood of further issues are:

- Visually inspect the drive, particularly the power connectors. Look for signs of burning or melting.
- Use a good surge suppressor or connect to a GFI outlet, which should trip if the drive is so badly damaged as to cause an actual short.
- Use a pencil eraser to clean the contacts on the drive before connecting it.